# HTML email - Long text with div overflow not working

Tags: html, css

I've a long text inside a `td`. I need the width of this text to be no longer than 350px. It should show a horizontal bar if the text width is longer than 350px. The code below works fine in browser. But it does not work in outlook email. Is there a way to get this to work in html email also?

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kedpjryk/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="max-width:350px; overflow:auto; white-space:nowrap">TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
table td {
    max-width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:400px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="table-layout;">
      <tr>
        <td>
TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST          
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OR** You can also add CSS directly to `td`. Like

```
<td style="max-width: 350px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES
    TTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTE
    STTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTT
    ESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST          
</td>
```

Comment: ellipsis works in browser but not in outlook html formatted email.

Comment: Yeah my bad, in outlook text doesn't wrap directly so you need to use **<table style=”word-break: break-all;”>**

Comment: Check this link it might help you too: **https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/prepare-emails-outlook-tricks#sm.001opxcp214loeydv3m2cjz39dy8y**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove css for table and td and can add an attribute inside  , style="max-width:100%"